# Increment array values

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have a array of integers.

Let's say:

```
int[] arr = {0,0,0};
```

I use a for loop to access array elements and then increment them by 1.

```java
private int[] someMethod() {
    int [] arr = {0,0,0};
       for(int i = 0 ;i < arr.length; i++) {
          arr[i]++;
        }
    return arr;
}
```

Then I get `[1,1,1]` every time.
But I want to get `[1,1,1]` then `[2,2,2]` then `[3,3,3]` and so on..

In other words, I want to increment the array that has been already incremented

I hope someone could help

Comment: Create a method, ``public void incrementArray(int[] arr)`` and put your loop in the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you reallocate the array at the beginning of your method instead of using the previous one that you changed.  But there is also a more compact way to do this.

I would use the `Arrays.setAll()` method.

- the first argument is the array.
- the second argument is a lambda that returns the index of each array element.

```
int[] arr = {0,0,0};
Arrays.setAll(arr, i->++arr[i]);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
Arrays.setAll(arr, i->++arr[i]);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Prints

```
[1, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 2]
```

If you want to incorporate it into your method you can do the following:

```
int[] arr = {0,0,0};
for(int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(someMethod(arr)));
}

public static int[] someMethod(int[] array) {        
    Arrays.setAll(array, i->++array[i]);
    return array;
}
```

Prints

```
[1, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 2]
[3, 3, 3]
[4, 4, 4]
[5, 5, 5]
```

Note that it is not necessary to return the array since you are passing a reference and changing its contents.  But in some cases it can make it easier to use (as in my previous example).

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a logic, or algorithmic problem, let me explain.
In your example you have an array of thee elements:

```
int [] arr = {0,0,0};
```

So the following function call

```
arr.length
```

will be equal 3.
In your loop you have a condition:

```
int i = 0 ;i<arr.length;i++
```

Which can be seen as:

```
int i = 0 ;i<3;i++
```

So, having this condition we can see, that i can be 0, 1, 2.
It mean, that each time when loop goes on, you increment only one element of array.
First time you do it for arr[0], next with arr[1]. So each arr element is incremented once.
If you want to increment each element each time, your code should be:

```
private int[] someMethod(){
int [] arr = {0,0,0};
for(int i = 0 ;i<arr.length;i++){
 for(int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
  arr[j]++;
 }
}
return arr;
}
```